# Installing extensions to Chrome profile. Protractor

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome-extension, automation, protractor

How to check that an extension was installed? I have tried manually and have not see it, but I am able to see it in Firefox.

helper.js:

```
var q = require('q');
var fs = require('fs');
exports.getCapabilities = function (filename) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    fs.readFile(filename, function (err, data) {
        var capabilities = {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {
                extensions: [
                    data.toString('base64')
                ]
            }
        };
        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
var helper = require('./helper.js');
directConnect: false,
    exports.config = {
        specs: ['spec.js'],
        chromeDriver: "chromedriver",
        framework: 'jasmine2',
        getMultiCapabilities: helper.getCapabilities("face.crx")
    };
```

Comment: What if you replace `getMultiCapabilities` with `getCapabilities`?

Comment: Its still the same, the only extension I have is "Chrome Automation Extension 1"